# What is the point of using "send" instead of a normal method call?

Tags: ruby, methods, send

as far as I understand 'send' method, this

```
some_object.some_method("im an argument")
```

is same as this

```
some_object.send :some_method, "im an argument"
```

So what is the point using 'send' method?

Comment: Because the parameter to `send` is a symbol, which can be held in a variable. E.g., `foo = :size; [].send foo`. While it can be used to access private methods, IMO its use as a generic messaging tool far outweighs its value as a way "around" the intent of a developer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It can come in handy if you don't know in advance the name of the method, when you're doing metaprogramming for example, you can have the name of the method in a variable and pass it to the `send` method.

It can also be used to call private methods, although this particular usage is not considered to be a good practice by most Ruby developers.

```
class Test
  private
  def my_private_method
    puts "Yay"
  end
end

t = Test.new

t.my_private_method # Error

t.send :my_private_method #Ok
```

You can use `public_send` though to only be able to call public methods.

Comment: The second use case is *far* more important than the first, IMO.

Comment: You can use `public_send` if your only intent is to call dynamically.

Comment: Using send is not a bad practice.

Comment: @christianblais He said that using send _to call private methods_ is a bad practice, and he's right, insomuch that doing anything to call private methods is a bad practice (they're private for a reason).

Comment: Rephrased and switched the use cases, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Intrepidd's use cases, it is convenient when you want to route different methods on the same receiver and/or arguments. If you have `some_object`, and want to do different things on it depending on what `foo` is, then without `send`, you need to write like:

```
case foo
when blah_blah then some_object.do_this(*some_arguments)
when whatever then some_object.do_that(*some_arguments)
...
end
```

but if you have `send`, you can write

```
next_method =
case foo
when blah_blah then :do_this
when whatever then :do_that
....
end
some_object.send(next_method, *some_arguments)
```

or

```
some_object.send(
  case foo
  when blah_blah then :do_this
  when whatever then :do_that
  ....
  end,
  *some_arguments
)
```

or by using a hash, even this:

```
NextMethod = {blah_blah: :do_this, whatever: :do_that, ...}
some_object.send(NextMethod[:foo], *some_arguments)
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to everyone else's answers, a good use case would be for iterating through methods that contain an incrementing digit.

```
class Something
  def attribute_0
    "foo"
  end
  def attribute_1
    "bar"
  end
  def attribute_2
    "baz"
  end
end

thing = Something.new

3.times do |x|
  puts thing.send("attribute_#{x}")
end

#=> foo
# bar
# baz
```

This may seem trivial, but it's occasionally helped me keep my Rails code and templates DRY.  It's a very specific case, but I think it's a valid one.

Comment: I'd say any naming that depends on incrementing digits is a serious code smell. The above class probably wants a method like `def attributes; ["foo", "bar", "baz"]; end`.

Comment: You are right. I was an idiot back then. But send still has its place as a metaprogramming tool, obviously.

Comment: To be clear: At no point did I call you an idiot, nor do I think you are one. Your example of `send` is totally valid, but hopefully the extra insight will be of use to less-experienced future readers.

Answer (score 0):

The summing briefly up what was already said by colleagues: `send` method is a syntax sugar for meta-programming. The example below demonstrates the case when native calls to methods are likely impossible:

```
class Validator
  def name
    'Mozart'
  end
  def location
    'Salzburg'
  end
end

v = Validator.new
'%name% was born in %location%'.gsub (/%(?<mthd>\w+)%/) do
  # v.send :"#{Regexp.last_match[:mthd]}"
  v.send Regexp.last_match[:mthd].to_sym
end
=> "Mozart was born in Salzburg"
```

Answer (score -1):

I like this costruction

```
Object.get_const("Foo").send(:bar)
```