# Confusion with call to "puts" in ruby

Tags: ruby

We all know the fact that in ruby the . operator with an object left to the `.` helps to send the message (right to the `.`).

With the above principle here with this - `"100".to_s` , we can say that `.` operator is sending the message `to_s` to the object `100`. Nice one!

So what about the `puts("hello")`? Here are my questions to local ruby experts:

1. where the . operator?
2. who is receiver here?

Comment: This is my **`KEEN`** request , not to `vote - up` this post. Down-votes are welcome only if applicable but after explanations. Without any requirement don't make my thread `dirty`.

Comment: Pro-tip: Use backticks only for code.

Comment: Another pro-tip: Don't abuse italics or bold faces.

Comment: I used those only to highlight the main objectives of my post.

Comment: "used those only to highlight objectives" - Don't. Instead use clear and concise wording, so that objectives are obvious and don't need to be highlighted.

Comment: You cannot ask for or against up votes or down votes. The users do it on their own will. And whatever question you ask, it is not going to be only yours. Any question here is intended for future readers to gain something from it.

Comment: @sawa - Yes, I have no problem with that, to share this nice thing I posted here. But I hate such voting especially in educations.

Comment: OP, is there a problem with my edit? I have simply removed all the clutter.

Comment: @phant0m: while you're on it, could you fix a typo in "receiever"? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Missed that one, I would, but I'll wait to hear back from the OP first.

Comment: Let me know I will fix it, don't need others to edit. last day someone's edit gave me too pain. I got `5` down -vote. whereas I shouldn't receive that.

Comment: Now you're doing it again, the backtick overuse.

Comment: It was already suggested by Sergio: `use clear and concise wording, so that objectives are obvious and don't need to be highlighted.` You didn't. So I edited the question for you. There is a reason everyone can edit anyone else's posts.

Comment: @phant0m: "everyone can edit anyone else's posts" - provided that one has enough rep, of course. We don't want a bunch of 1-rep users editing posts left and right :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - any more improvement- advice please?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Of course, they just need to get reviewed. Flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: @TheMiddleMan: it's an improvement, but phant0m's version is better, IMO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Receiver in this case is implicit `self`. `puts` is a method of `Kernel`. All classes include Kernel module, so **all** objects have a `puts` method on them. The only thing is: it's private. Private methods can only be called with implicit `self` (or using `send`)

```
puts 'foo' # >> foo
1.puts 'bar' # ~> -:3:in `<main>': private method `puts' called for 1:Fixnum (NoMethodError)


1.send :puts, 'bar' # >> bar
```

Comment: As usual you are the best, from the core platform.

Comment: Could you please just explain the technique you used here with `1.puts` and `1.send`? what you actually trying to show me? But my bad :( i am not getting that.

Comment: It's an illustration to the answer. `puts` is a private method on all objects. You can't call private methods like you call public methods. That's all.

Comment: Also, docs on [Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send)

Comment: Nice question about `.send` was asked today http://stackoverflow.com/q/14793048/1136008

Comment: @A.D. Thanks for your complement!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev to be more precise, all objects *include* `Kernel`, not *inherit from* it, since `Kernel` is a module rather than class.

Comment: @mudasobwa: absolutely, thanks for the correction. What I was meaning to say is that all objects inherit Kernel's *functionality*. But for the sake of technical accuracy, I have updated the post.

Answer (score 2):

The receiver is omitted, and is `self` in that context. Therefore, the `.` is omitted too. `puts` is a method on `Kernel`, and whatever the receiver is, it can access `puts` since `Kernel` is included in any class that has an instance.

Comment: receiver is not necessarily `main`. It's implicit self. On top level in IRB session it's `main`, yes. But `puts` works everywhere and `main` is not `self` everywhere :)

Comment: more functional answer,it is, not like- sorry!

Comment: This answer really would create confusion for future readers I think.

Comment: @TheMiddleMan In what way?

Comment: @TheMiddleMan I don't think that will lead to "confusion".

Comment: what I felt i said, rest up to you. As you don't know who is going to read the your answer next, how much capable is he? So your explanation might not be useful for him, it would then only play the role of placeholder of an answer. In programming language I think answer should come with description with code, not the either alone.